Is there a way to trigger a function in a Python script by following a Markdown link in VSCode?
I have written a Python function (let's call it set_entry()) that takes a word as an argument and writes a Markdown file that lists a variety of lexical and orthographic relations that word possesses to other words in the English language. I am curious whether there is a way of having my Python script watch whichever Markdown file I currently have open in the Preview window, and trigger the creation and opening of a new Markdown file using the set_entry() function any time I follow a link for a file that does not already exist in the directory.
I am using Visual Studio Code both as an IDE as well as Markdown viewer. Now, I could run the whole dictionary through this function (which was the original plan), but that would take a while on my computer, and if I ever rejig the function to include more information, I would have run it all over again. If I can set up something that seamlessly creates new files as I need them, like a slightly laggy Wiktionary, it would enable me to begin my project earlier than otherwise.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Could you share more detail about the feature you want?
